# How to convert a numpy array of eight bytes to an int64?

Tags: numpy, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert an array of 8 byte numpy arrays to an array of int64s

A sample of my input looks like this (This is a print of variable 'gids') -

```
[[b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b'1']
 [b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b'2']]
```

The inputs are fixed width of the eight characters

I'm trying to use the following to do the conversion

```
gids2=np.frombuffer(gids, dtype=np.int64)
```

Which is yielding the following output,

```
[3539864629463228448 3611922223501156384]
```

The requited values are [1,2]

Any guidance on what I'm doing wrong here will be appreciated. My use case involves tens of millions of these conversions so I'm quite sensitive to performance

**Update:**
I am now able to complete the conversion correctly using the following

```
gids2=gids.view('S8').astype('int64')
```

However, I'm not sure this is the most efficient/fastest way to do the conversion?